# How can i use 38 classes instead of 1000 in model.predict decode predictions

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning

i am founding an error in plant disease detection using resnet50 deep learning model  every time it raises an error message in decode_predictions

## error

expects a batch of predictions (i.e. a 2D array of shape (samples, 1000)). Found array with shape: (1, 38)"

```
enter code here


model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet',include_top=False,classes=38)

try:
model = load_model('/content/drive/My 
Drive/color/checkpoints/ResNet50_model_weights.h5')
print("model loaded")  
except:
print("model not loaded")

img_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/color/test/0/appleblackrot188.jpg' 
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(300, 300))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)

preds = model.predict(x)
print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds,top=3)[0])
```

Comment: Your post is hard to understand. Please check the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) - I think the first paragraph needs *a* **little** `bit` of ***formatting***!

Comment: sir i want to predict the image of a plant between 38 classes but it in code it shows me an error in last line of code plz check the code

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the preprocesing function:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
# Using the keras wrapper on tensorflow (it must be the same using just keras).

IMAGE = [] # From image source, i did it from the camera.

toPred = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input(np.expand_dims(tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(IMAGE), axis=0))
```

Maybe that can help :)

Comment: sir i  tried this method but i raise the same error kindly help

Answer (score 0):

decode_predictions works only for ImageNet (no. of classes = 1000). For these 38 classes of plants, you have to write your own decode predictions based on the ground truth label you've assigned for each plant.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need an index JSON file and create a new decode_predictions function.
For example

This HAM10000 that has 7 classes and you need to split to each folder like this

[image]

then make an index JSON file like this

```
{
"0" : [
    "AKIEC",
    "akiec"
],
"1" : [
    "BCC",
    "bcc"
],
"2" : [
    "BKL",
    "bkl"
],
"3" : [
    "DF",
    "df"
],
"4" : [
    "MEL",
    "mel"
],
"5" : [
    "NV",
    "nv"
],
"6" : [
    "VASC",
    "vasc"
]
```

}

Then try this code

```
def decode_predictions(preds, top=4, class_list_path='/content/SKIN_DATA/HAM10000_index.json'):
  if len(preds.shape) != 2 or preds.shape[1] != 7: # your classes number
    raise ValueError('`decode_predictions` expects '
                     'a batch of predictions '
                     '(i.e. a 2D array of shape (samples, 1000)). '
                     'Found array with shape: ' + str(preds.shape))
  index_list = json.load(open(class_list_path))
  results = []
  for pred in preds:
    top_indices = pred.argsort()[-top:][::-1]
    result = [tuple(index_list[str(i)]) + (pred[i],) for i in top_indices]
    result.sort(key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)
    results.append(result)
  return results
```